# FastAPI query using response_model with a pydantic schema returns ValidationError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

Using I have an application using FastAPI (0.95.0), SQLAlchemy (2.0.8) and Pydantic (1.10.7).

I am querying a database and want the return values to be defined by a Pydantic scheme.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, status, Depends
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

from .database import get_db
import models # here, models.Entries is defined

from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

class InputSchema(BaseModel):
    url: str
    param1: Optional[str] 
    # ...

class Retrieval(BaseModel):
    url: str  # url is the PK and not nullable 

    class Config:
        orm_model = True


@app.post("/get_something", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response_model=Retrieval)
async def get_some(input_params: InputSchema, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    query = db.query(models.Entries).filter(models.Entries.param1 == input_params.param1)
    results = query.all()
    return {"myres":results}
```

I would expect to get this:

```
{"myres": [{"url": "www.stackoverflow.com"}, {"url":"www.github.com"}]}
```

Instead, I get this:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Retrieval
response -> url
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

If I set `url` to `url: Optional[str]`, the app returns `{"myres":null}`.

Hence, what am I doing wrong and how can I get the expected results?

Comment: Your response model is `Retrieval` but you are returning a dict with one key called `"myres"`. How is Pydantic going to make a `Retrieval` from that dict? You may get away with returning `{"url": something}` and returning `Retrieval(url=something)` will work but what you have right now obviously won't.

Comment: @FiddleStix, I thought Pydantic would change/filter/cast the returned variable to the defined schema. Even if I change my return to `return results`, I still get a validation error. Printing `type(results)` shows `<class 'list'>` - if that is of any help...

Comment: You should probably read the FastAPI documentation (again). If you know the schema you want, then define your Pydantic models accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You response must comply with your response model. So if you want to get list of model you should specify this. You can read more about response model in [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/)

```
@app.post("/get_something", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response_model=List[Retrieval])
async def get_some(input_params: InputSchema, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    query = db.query(models.Entries).filter(models.Entries.param1 == input_params.param1)
    results = query.all()
    return results
```